# python too many keyword argument

Tags: python, arguments

The code below can use same data as input but I need to use **_ to avoid too many argument.
Is any way that remove the parameter **_ and input the correct parameter to f1 and f2?

```
def f1(freq,bw,**_):
    print(freq,bw)
def f2(FW_ID,**_):
    print(FW_ID)
db = {
    'freq':2414,
    'bw':20,
    'FW_ID':0.1,
    }

f1(**db)
f2(**db)
```

Comment: Why don't you pass the respective field values individually?

Comment: because  I read script to my function and combine to  format like list = (f1,db),(f2,db),(f3,db)....(f100,db)] when I run script f1(**db), f2(**db) but unfortunate 
db is some  var read from script like.,freq=2412,bw=20...etc but there are some variable not read from script (for ex sys_path,log_path) so That will creat some unneedful parameter in db so I have to use  **_ to catch

Answer (score 2):

Any method you try and hack this to save lines of code, would be unreadable, and would lead to bugs that are difficult to trace when your data in `db` is malformed.

Do it the correct way, by being [explicit, not implicit](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/). Call `f1` and `f2` like this:

```
f1(freq=db['freq'], bw=db['bw'])
f2(FW_ID=db['FW_ID'])
```

Or even just:

```
f1(db['freq'], db['bw'])
f2(db['FW_ID'])
```

If you do that than there's no need for your `**_` argument, and you can write a more readable function signature:

```
def f1(freq,bw):
    print(freq,bw)

def f2(FW_ID):
    print(FW_ID)
```

An alternative to all that is to have both functions accept the full `db` (`dict`) as an argument, and parse it inside (but that might be too repetitive)

Comment: In real case, I wish many fun can use same input will much simple

Comment: so use f1(db['freq'], db['bw']) will work but less efficient if i have f1~f100

Comment: I need to handle this 100 diff case

Answer (score 0):

If you try to pass each key individually you shouldn't have a problem, i.e.:

```
def f1(freq,bw):
    print(freq,bw)
def f2(FW_ID):
    print(FW_ID)
db = {
    'freq':2414,
    'bw':20,
    'FW_ID':0.1,
    }

f1(db['freq'], db['bw'])

2414 20

f2(db['FW_ID'])

0.1
```

Best of luck!

Comment: In real case, I wish many fun can use same input will much simple 
so use f1(db['freq'], db['bw']) will work but less efficient 
if i have f1~f100 ,I need to handle this 100 diff case –

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with a decorator that catches bad arguments?

```
import inspect

def catch_bad_args(func):
    def func_new(*args, **kwargs):
        argnames, _, _, _ = inspect.getargspec(func)
        kwargs = {k:v for k,v in kwargs.items() if k in argnames}
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return func_new

@catch_bad_args
def f1(freq, bw):
    print(freq, bw)

@catch_bad_args
def f2(FW_ID):
    print(FW_ID)

db = {
    'freq':2414,
    'bw':20,
    'FW_ID':0.1,
}

f1(**db)
f2(**db)
```

Output:

```
2414 20
0.1
```

Comment: I know you mean but use decorator is almost like I add **_ and will down the performance...

Comment: I think the best way is using decorator but consider the performance I think using **_ is the only way...

Comment: @黃瀚嶙 The decorator might be more descriptive. You could throw in `functools.wraps` and users would not see anything but the valid arguments when reading the function documentation.